# Multiplication and addition from multiple tables (Simple stockmarket program)

Tags: mysql

I have the 3 following tables: Bonds, Inventory and Customer.

**Stocks** contains: name, ticker(pk), latest

**Inventory** contains: ssn(pk), ticker(pk), amount

**Customer** contains: name, ssn(pk), assets

I wanna show how much value each person has on the account by multiplying the amount of stocks with the value of the stocks and then adding the assets for each person.

```
SELECT Customer.name AS "Customers Name", SUM(amount*latest) + assets AS "Total value"

FROM Customer, Inventory, Stocks

WHERE Inventory.ssn = Customer.ssn AND Stocks.ticker = Inventory.ticker
```

This just shows one person and it shows the wrong amount of value (way too high) I'm guessing the code just takes all the Stocks* latest value and adds it together for one person.

My expected outcome is a table with the customers name and total value on the same row, showing all the customers in one table

SOLVED BY DOING THIS

```
SELECT 
    C.name AS "Customers Name", SUM(I.amount*S.latest) + C.assets AS "Total value"
FROM Customer as C
INNER JOIN Inventory as I on I.ssn = C.ssn
INNER JOIN Stocks    as S on S.ticker = I.ticker
GROUP BY C.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT 
    C.name AS "Customers Name", SUM(I.amount*S.latest) + C.assets AS "Total value"
FROM Customer as C
INNER JOIN Inventory as I on I.ssn = C.ssn
INNER JOIN Stocks    as S on S.ticker = I.ticker
```

Comment: Just one customer shows up and not a list of all customers still.

Comment: Try to replace INNER JOIN by LEFT JOIN so, but need sample data to answer where is the problem because for me it's because you have only ONE customer that respect both join condition

Comment: Changing to left join gave a new customer but still just one and a new total value which is still wrong. I'm not sure how to give you sample data as I have the database in another language.

Comment: So it's not a query problem but you just have one customer in your database that has a valid join on inventory by ssn param AND a stocks join to this inventory by ticker param

Comment: In the Inventory only some people exist, it shows the customers ssn and which ticker they have a certain amount of. Some ssn exists multiple times with different tickers becuase they have invested in more than one stock. But more than one person fits the requirement for the join.

Comment: As I said, can't help you more if I have no idea what you get in your database :/